# forms problem in django 1.1

Tags: django, forms

I have the following form:

```
class ModuleItemForm2(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Module_item
        fields = ('title', 'media', 'thumb', 'desc', 'default', 'player_option')
```

The model is:

```
class Module_item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    layout = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=LAYOUTS_CHOICE)
    media = models.CharField(help_text='Media url', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    conserv = models.ForeignKey(Conserv, help_text= 'Redirect to Conserv', blank=True, null=True)
    conserve_section = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text= 'Section within the redirected Conserv', blank=True, null=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', help_text='Upper menu.', blank=True, null=True)
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, blank=True, null=True)
    thumb = models.FileField(upload_to='sms/module_items/thumbs', blank=True, null=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    auto_play = models.IntegerField(help_text='Auto start play (miliseconds)', blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(help_text='Display order', blank=True, null=True)
    depth = models.IntegerField(help_text='The layout depth', blank=True, null=True)
    flow_replace = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    default = models.IntegerField(help_text='The selected sub item (Note: Starting from 0)', blank=True, null=True)
    player_options = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
```

In my view I build form:

```
module_item_form2 = ModuleItemForm2()

print module_item_form2
```

And I get the following error on the print line:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'label'
```

It works fine with django 1.0.2. I see the error only in django 1.1.

Do you have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Regards, Arshavski Alexander.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `player_options` in the model, but `player_option` in the list of form fields. Does it work if you add the `s` in the form fields tuple?